# Feed keys visual mode and pressing enter?

Tags: vimscript

I'm running the following command, but the `\<CR>` becomes part of the regular expression in feedkeys...

`:call feedkeys("0v/\(,\|$\)\<CR>")`

Is there a way to make it an enter keypress instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the backslashes are picked up by the double-quoted string in the `feedkeys()` command. You'll need to use `\\` if you want to pass literal backslashes:

```
:call feedkeys("0v/\\(,\\|$\\)\<CR>")
```

This command suffers from a mild case of [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome). You can make it a bit simpler by adding `\\v` so that you don't need to add so many backslashes in the first place:

```
:call feedkeys("0v/\\v(,|$)\<CR>")
```

For single quotes strings no backslashes have a special meaning, so you could also use:

```
:call feedkeys('0v/\(,\|$\)' . "\<CR>")
```

or:

```
:call feedkeys('0v/\(,\|$\)^[')
```

Where `^[` is the literal Enter character (you can enter this by pressing `<C-v><Enter>`, it should show up in a different colour).

Comment: Can also use `"\n"` as Enter key